# NativeScript Javascript object properties undefined

Tags: javascript, object, properties, nativescript, object-property

I have searched for answers, but none can solve my problem

I am new to nativescript. I just follow every step that the ebook does.

the code in the ebook works fine, but mine doesnt

here is the code(or ebook page 158,159 or pdf page 178,179)
ebook: https://www.nativescript.org/get-the-nativescript-book

scrapbook.js

```
var observable = require("data/observable");
exports.onLoaded = function(args) {
  var page = args.object;
  var scrapbook = new observable.fromObject({
  genders: ["Female", "Male", "Other"] });
  page.bindingContext = scrapbook;
};
exports.onTap = function(args) {
  var page = args.object; 
  var scrapbook = page.bindingContext; 
  console.log("You have made " + scrapbook.title); 
  console.log("Age: " + scrapbook.date.toLocaleDateString());
  console.log("Gender selected:" + scrapbook.genders[scrapbook.gender]);
```

scrapbook.xml

```
<Page loaded="onLoaded">
<StackLayout>
    <Label text="Title: " />
    <TextField class="header" text="{{title}}" />
    <Label text="Age: " />
    <DatePicker date="{{ date }}" />
    <Label text="Gender: " />
    <ListPicker items="{{ genders }}" selectedIndex="{{gender }}" /> 
    <Button tap="onTap" text="Done" />
</StackLayout>
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLocaleDateString' of undefined

if I remove the "toLocaleDateString"

it prints:

LOG from device Galaxy C5: You have made undefined

LOG from device Galaxy C5: Age: undefined

LOG from device Galaxy C5: Gender selected:undefined

Comment: Your scrapbook Observable has only `genders` defined in it. Any other properties will be undefined of course, you have to define them before using it.

Comment: thx a lot, problem solved